# Make large numbers worth less than small numbers (JS)

Tags: javascript, math

I need to find out how to make smaller numbers worth more than bigger numbers, and vice versa. For example, if I have numbers 1-5, I want 5 to be worth the least and 1 to be worth the most. I can't seem to find something on this topic, so it's either impossible or, I just don't quite know how to phrase the search. Either way, I didn't want to be too specific so my question can be applicable to to others, but this is a coding question I am having issues with in my game.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "worth less" mean? A number is what it is. The context in which "worth less" is used is very important and should be *included* in the question. (This question is unlikely to be useful to others because it is *not specific enough*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sorting in descending order? If the numbers are in an array the following would sort them in that order:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return b - a;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be clear about what you mean by "worth less". Are you trying to make (1<5) evaluate to false? If so, there are much much better ways of doing it.

One trick though -- you can just multiply everything by -1.

Comment: No see, it's terrible complicated to explain :( multiplying by negative one doesn't help... but by worth less, essentaially all I need to to is find a way to do this.. let's say var one = 1; var two = 2; and so on to five. Now, I need to find a piece of code to take var one = 5, var two = 4, var 3 = 3; var 2 = 2; var 1 = 1; Nope, it's not as simple as that, because I won't know the numbers. But they will be kind of like this, 1-5, or 1-9 or one to something,